# Salesforce - Newbie to Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I could use some general assistance with a simple bit of Apex code. Just so you know I am a newbie to Salesforce.com, but not to web application programming (12 years but with Coldfusion and some Perl and am used to the MVC architecture), although I have not been exposed deeply to Java or C#.

So I am working on a simple controller that I'll use in a simple VF page. I'd just like to return the value and display it on the page but Im running into some syntax issues during compile. Here's my code so far:

Controller - mytest.cls

```
    public with sharing class myTest {

    public class addNewFolder {

        String tmpFolderName = 'MyTestFolder';
        String tmpObjectID = '22K22'; 

        String tmpResult = 'Whoo-hoo!';
        System.debug('XIX|' + tmpResult);
        return tmpResult;

    }

}
```

Error

Description Resource Path Location Type
Save error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'XIX|' mytest.cls /PREPROD/src/classes line 15 Force.com save problem

Comment: You have code that's not in any method, you need to move your code into an actual method definition.

Comment: Thanks - here's a link to the SF dev forum on the same subject. I believe you are correct @superfell: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Newbie-Apex-Question/td-p/433253

Answer (score 1):

As I understand

> addNewFolder

is a METHOD. So instead of writing

> public class addNewFolder

you must write 
`public string addNewFolder() {... return tmpResult;}`

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `|` character is causing the error. You could try escaping the `|` character like this:

```
System.debug('XIX\\|' + tmpResult);
```

Or, you could use a different character:

```
System.debug('XIX-' + tmpResult);
```

**Update**: Upon looking more carefully at your code, I realized [superfell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41455/superfell) is right (see his comment on your question above).